# 2D quadrant sandpile: emergent highway structure

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, cellular-automata

Consider the top-right quadrant of the plane divided into unit cells, each cell containing some number of chips. A cell containing at least two chips can *fire* two chips, one to the cell above it and another to the cell to the right. The firing continues until each cells contains at most one chip. This is very similar to the [abelian sandpile model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model), perhaps a simpler variant.

Let $S_n$ be the final configuration after $n$ chips are initially placed in the bottom left cell.
$S_{2^{16}}$ is pictured below, scaled and rotated $45$ degrees. Cells that never hold a chip are uncolored, and green and blue represent having one and zero chips in the end respectively.

[image]

Also here are mesmerizing [GIFs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvR9X.jpg) of adding $1000$ chips one by one, and adding $32$ chips $500$ times.

The part near the corner seems to be chaotic, but there is a very prominent "highway" structure extending to the top-right, filled with nested slanted chains of triangles, seemingly self-similar.

**Q0**. Why the highway appears at all? Looking at the standard sandpile, it would be natural to expect the picture to be somewhat uniform in the quarter-circle around the corner, yet it propels quite rapidly instead.

**Q1**. How can the structure of the triangle chains in $S_n$ be explained, or at least described?

**Q2**. Let $L(n)$ be the largest coordinate of a touched cell in $S_n$ (length of the highway), and $D(n)$ be the largest $|x - y|$ in $S_n$ (half-width of the highway). It appears that $L(n) \sim n^{2/3}$ and $D(n) \sim n^{1/3}$. How can this be explained?

Comment: I would describe it as pretty.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but I believe the reason your model "propels quite rapidly" compared to the standard ASM on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is that there is no "backflow": chips are never sent back towards the origin.